# GA transator nto displaying

Tags: html, css, translation

http://sr.umph.us/

I have added GA Translator to my site and i can see it works fine in the admin area but on the front end of my site i just can't get the flags to display.

Admin

[image]

Frontend

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Cheers
Dave

Answer (score 0):

You have `div` with ID `flags` in wrong place. Its in `BODY`, but it has to be inside `div` with ID `glt-translate-trigger`.

Now you have it like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="glt-translate-trigger">
    <span class="notranslate">Translate »</span>
  </div>
  <div id="flags">
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

It has to be like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="glt-translate-trigger">
    <span class="notranslate">Translate »</span>
    <div id="flags">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

Also then you have to set up your CSS as it is in your admin, but first at all you have to move `div` with ID `flags` inside that `div`. I checked it on your frontend through `firebug` and its working.